# Can python script converted to exe get it's name?

Tags: python

When i have python code (sample.py). Where is just code `Print(__file__)`, the output is `sample.py`. When i convert it to exe with auto-py-to-exe (it name will be sample2.exe) the output is `sample.py` and not sample2.exe. How can i print sample2.exe?

Comment: `print(sys.executable)`

Comment: Yes this work Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys
print((sys.executable))
```